# Remove all UITextView's Gesture Recognizers

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I am developing an app that has a UITextView within a custom UITableViewCell in a tableview. The tableviewcell has several gesture recognizers. My problem is that the textview is responding to touches before the tableViewCell's recognizers. I have a long tap for moving the cell to another location but instead the textview will try and select it's text for copy/paste/magnifying glass functions. Also, the textview is swallowing touches from the tableview itself and so scrolling will not function within the tableview if you begin the scroll touching the textview.

even with the editable property set to false the textview still wants to select text and show the magnifying glass.

Initially I had everything working using a UITextField instead of a UITextView but I need support for multiple lines of text.

So how can I keep the textview from swallowing any touch event? Any suggestions or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if your text on UITextView is pre fixed and need not to be edited at run time then set it's property to Editable = FALSE;

Comment: The text isnt fixed. It's an input field similar to the iphones sms app. even when the editable property if false it still wants magnify text for copy/past functionality as well as swallowing the scroll from the uitableview

Comment: Do you respond to taps on the cell (`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`)? If not, perhaps you could initially set the text view's `userInteraction` property as `NO`, and upon the user tapping the cell, you can make the text view the first responder... you should also set the owning view controller as the text view's delegate and listen for `textViewDidChange`... perhaps look for `\n` to denote when you should resign first responder... we kinda do it like this, and it works okay... geez this comment got long, I'll add some code as an answer...

Comment: Something is missing for me to understand the entire flow. When should the textview be editable? When editable and user is inputting text, should then the textview capture events? How does input end?

Comment: JGR - I have tried setting the userinteraction property to NO and just using a tap gesture added to the cell to switch it back over for editing purposes. That fixes all the issues except that I still cant scroll the tableview if I start scrolling from within the bounds of the textview.

Comment: Instead of adding a tap gesture, why not use the tableView delegate method `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and check to see if the selected cell has a text view?

Comment: That is, check perhaps in the indexPath's corresponding data model is represented by a text view cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how we handle `UITextView` user interaction that is contained within a `UITableViewCell`:

1) Your `UIViewController` should conform to `UITableViewDataSource`, `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITextViewDelegate` :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interace MyExampleController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextViewDelegate>
```

2) Initially, the text view's `userInteractionEnabled` property is set to `NO`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *textViewCellIdentifier = @"MyTextViewCellIdentifier";
     MyTextViewViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:textViewCellIdentifier];

     if (!cell)
     {
         // ... do your stuff to create the cell...
         cell.textView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
         cell.textView.delegate = self;
     }

     // do whatever else to set the cell text, etc you need...

     return cell;
}
```

3) Check if a text view cell was tapped via `UITableViewDelegate` method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    BOOL isTextViewCell = ... // do your check here to determine if this cell has a text view

    if (isTextViewCell)
    {
        [[(MyTextTableViewCell *)cell textView] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [[(MyTextTableViewCell *)cell textView] becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else
    {
        // ... do whatever else you do...
    }
}
```

4) Check for `\n` to determine when to have the textView resign first responder (passed when user presses the `return` key):

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
    {
        if ([text rangeOfString:@"\n"].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [textView resignFirstResponder];
            textView.
            return NO;
        }

        return YES;
    }
```

5) Save text into your model once after the text view has resigned (ends editing):

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSString *text = textView.text;
    // do your saving here    
}
```

This was mostly written on the spot, so there may be some minor errors in there, but hopefully you get the general idea.

Good luck.